# Using TypeClass Instances Within Typeclasses

Tags: typeclass, coq

I am trying to define two instances of a type class, one of which will use the other's instance. However, unless I bind the function's name outside of the second definition Coq is unable to determine it should use the type class instance from bexp (take a look at the comment for dirty hack). Is there a way to avoid this sort of hack in Coq?

```
Class Compilable ( A : Type ) := { compile : A -> bool }.

Inductive cexp : Type :=
| CAnd :  cexp -> cexp -> cexp
| COr  :  cexp -> cexp -> cexp
| CProp : bexp -> cexp.  


Instance: Compilable bexp :=
  { compile :=
      fix compile b :=
          match b with
          (* elided *)
          end
  }.

Definition compile2 := compile.

Instance: Compilable cexp :=
  { compile :=
      fix compile c :=
        match c with
        | CAnd x y => (compile x) && (compile y)
        | COr x y => (compile x) || (compile y)
        | CProp e => (compile2 e) (* <-- dirty hack *)
        end
  }.
```

Comment: Have you tried renaming `compile` in `fix compile` and its body into something else?

Comment: @AntonTrunov that works --- thanks! That still feels somewhat hackish, but is much better. Haskell for example is able to handle this with little trouble.

Answer (score 3):

This can be fixed if we replace `compile` with some other name (`rec`) like so:

```
Instance: Compilable cexp :=
  { compile :=
      fix rec c :=
        match c with
        | CAnd x y => (rec x) && (rec y)
        | COr x y => (rec x) || (rec y)
        | CProp e => (compile e)
        end
  }.
```

In [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44638611/using-typeclass-instances-within-typeclasses#comment76265016_44638611) the OP pointed out that Haskell easily deals with this situation. To understand the reason why Coq does not do it let us take a look at the type of `compile`:

```
About compile.
```

> ```
> compile : forall A : Type, Compilable A -> A -> bool
> ```
>
> Arguments `A`, `Compilable` are implicit and maximally inserted

We can see that Coq is more explicit about how typeclasses work. When you call `compile e` Coq sort of inserts placeholders standing for the implicit arguments like so `@compile _ _ e` (see [these slides](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/courses/670Fall12/slides.pdf), pages 21-25 for more detail). But with `fix compile c` you shadowed the previous binding, hence the type error.